# UIView Overlaps statusbar in ios 7

Tags: ios

I have a uitable view inside a uiview controller. I have used custom uitableview cell. Each cell has a textfield. So it happens when i edit those textfields, keyboard hides text field. In order to avoid that i am making the view to animate up. But the problem is that, my views background color is white. When the view is moved up, it overlaps above the status bar. I have a navigation bar in the view. When view is moved up, its overlapping status bar. I have set the color of status bar. when the view is moved up, the status bar becomes tranparent and i cud see the contents.

I know if i use uitableview controller, its simple but i want it should be subclass of uitableview controller. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your interface, make sure the underlying view does not occlude any of the statusBar, (ie the status bar and your view do not overlap at all)

Then set the `masksToBounds` property of the CALayer of your view to `YES` like this

```
someView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

This will clip any subview that extends beyond the bounds of your view.